# Как сконвертировать .py в .exe с помощью pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Ну всем привет.
Я написал свое десктоп приложение и оно запускается как и должно.Но только через консоль. А пользователю нужна .exe сборка для использования. Я установил pyinstaller. И как написано во всех мануалах использовал `pyinstaller name.py`.Пытался использовать все возможные флаги. Но при сборке возникает куча предпреждений. Вот ссылки на лог конвертации в habrastorage.
[Первая](https://habrastorage.org/webt/ky/pa/hp/kypahpcvx_f5t0nekkylcu4jopw.png)

[Вторая](https://habrastorage.org/webt/ys/jx/gv/ysjxgvg0u1vgbsafykomdujtwcy.png)
[И третяя](https://habrastorage.org/webt/ol/xu/3k/olxu3kdpiu8hu3gqwxs2r0_xsys.png)

Comment: Приложение консольное или оконное?

Comment: Оконное. Там разница между оконным и консольным только в одном флаге при конвертации.

Comment: Qt? Tk? GTK? Добавьте в вопрос весь лог сборки

Answer (score 1):

заходишь в командной строке в папку с файлом и пишешь

```
pyinstaller --onefile имя_файла.py
```

Comment: куча ошибок выдает

Comment: Возможно, Вы считаете, что я экстрасенс и умею читать мысли. Но нет. Какие именно ошибки? Скриншот или текст.

Comment: Простите если я вас обидел.Но я не знаю куда понятнее это объяснить.И честно говоря я уже не знаю куда и как прикрепить фото.Если можете скажите

Comment: Картинки можно загружать сюда https://ru.imgbb.com/

Comment: Сейчас закину лог конвертации

Comment: Лучше добавьте лог в сам вопрос, а не в комментарии

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая проблема, в .exe не упаковывалась нужная библиотека, как в итоге программа не запускалась. Решил следующим образом в папку где находился основной файл name.py скопировал папку необходимой библиотеки, а при создании .exe файла через pyinstaller в коммандной строке использовал флаг --patsh=name_library, где name_library - это имя библиотеки.[image: pykey.py-название главного файла, keyboard - папка с библиотекой, вверху в коммандной строке видно флаг --paths=keyboard который импортирует библиоткеу в .exe]

Comment: pykey.py - мой файл который надо превратить в .exe, папка keyboard - папка с библиотекой которую надо импортировать, в коммандной строке выше можно увидеть что я использую флаг --paths==keyboard - который добавляет библиотеку в .exe.